# How can I properly sort an array and remove duplicates in JavaScript with only one variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a working code that sorts an array from highest to lowest id, then removes duplicates.

Let's say we have an array of activities:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        contact_id: 2,
        some_field: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        contact_id: 3,
        some_field: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        contact_id: 4,
        some_field: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        contact_id: 3,
        some_field: true
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        contact_id: 4,
        some_field: false
    }
]
```

So the output with duplicate `contact_id` removed and arranged from highest id to lowest id must be:

```
[
    {
        id: 5,
        contact_id: 4,
        some_field: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        contact_id: 3,
        some_field: true
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        contact_id: 2,
        some_field: true
    }
]
```

My code looks like this:

```
// Sort by latest to oldest activity
arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.id > a.id);
// Remove duplicates
arr = arr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj['contact_id']).indexOf(obj['contact_id']) === pos;
});
```

While the code works, is there a better way to do this? like instead of having the arr variable set twice?

Comment: Well, sort mutates the array in-place, so you wouldn't need to return the result to a variable to filter 'arr'.

Comment: "While the code works, is there a better way to do this?" For code review, please ask in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: agree on moving this to codereview. there are several existing bugs in the code fragment

Comment: Note that this is not how `sort` works.  The function passed to `sort` should return a negative number, positive number or zero, if, respectively, the first value is less than, greater than, or equal to, the second one.

Comment: @henry thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4):

As other responses have noted, your use of the `sort()` function is inappropriate. The function passed to sort should return Numbers greater than or less than 0 - not booleans. That said, if you wish to continue with your current approach, you could just chain your two statements together like so:

```
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    contact_id: 2,
    some_field: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    contact_id: 3,
    some_field: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    contact_id: 4,
    some_field: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    contact_id: 3,
    some_field: true
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    contact_id: 4,
    some_field: false
  }
];

arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.id > a.id).filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
  return (
    arr.map(mapObj => mapObj["contact_id"]).indexOf(obj["contact_id"]) === pos
  );
});

console.log(arr);
```

I'm not so sure how much I like this solution - it seems harder for readers of your code to understand. That said, it definitely works as intended for your specific test case (although, as noted above, it may not work with others) - you can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gnnfpcv4/1/).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the sort is incorrect. (If `b.id < a.id`, the comparator returns 0, which identifies the values as ‘equal’.) For an unstable sort like in JavaScript, this is going to cause issues. The easiest solution would be to change the sort to `b.id - a.id`. And as others have said, the filter plus map makes the whole algorithm O(n^2), which could be improved to O(nlogn) with a hashset.

Comment: His question had a limited scope - he just wanted to lower the number of variable assignments. You and the other responses are right though - this isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: Cool, yeah – I would probably just edit the line: “This works as intended,” or add a fix for the sort :) (Edit: Wow – quick edit! +1)

Answer (score 4):

Note, first off, that there are several problems with this code:

- This is not how `sort` works. The function passed to sort should return a negative number, positive number or zero, if the first value is, respectively, less than, greater than, or equal to, the second one.  While it may seem to work for your specific test case, returning a boolean is a bad idea.
- This is a very painful way of collecting the unique values.  On every `filter` iteration, you rebuild your entire list of keys.  Then for each one, you scan through that list checking to find if your current value is included.  IMHO, it would be significantly cleaner to use a `Set` to store the keys, and test whether that Set has the given key before adding it to the output.

---

While the answers from Sreekath and HMR are fine, I am a big fan of the functional programming library [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com).  (Disclaimer: I'm one of its authors.)  I tend to think in terms of simple, reusable functions.

When I think of how to solve this problem, I think of it through a Ramda viewpoint.  And I would probably solve this problem like this:

```js
const {pipe, sortBy, prop, reverse, uniqBy} = R

const convert = pipe(
  sortBy(prop('id')),
  reverse,
  uniqBy(prop('contact_id'))
)

const arr = [{"contact_id": 2, "id": 1, "some_field": true}, {"contact_id": 3, "id": 2, "some_field": true}, {"contact_id": 4, "id": 3, "some_field": false}, {"contact_id": 3, "id": 4, "some_field": true}, {"contact_id": 4, "id": 5, "some_field": false}]


console.log(convert(arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

I think that is fairly readable, at least once you understand that `pipe` creates a pipeline of functions, each handing its result to the next one.

Now, there is often not a reason to include a large library like Ramda to solve a fairly simple problem.  But all the functions used in that version are easily reusable.  So it might make sense to try to create your own versions of these functions and keep them available to the rest of your application.  In fact, that's how libraries like Ramda actually get built.

So here is a version that has simple implementations of those functions, ones you might place in a utility library:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => (arg) => fns.reduce((a, f) => f(a), arg)
const prop = (name) => (obj) => obj[name]
const reverse = (xs) => xs.slice(0).reverse()
const sortBy = (fn) => (xs) => xs.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {  
  const aa = fn(a), bb = fn(b)
  return aa < bb ? -1 : aa > bb ? 1 : 0
})
const uniqBy = (fn) => (xs) => {
  const keys = new Set(), result = [];
  xs.forEach(x => {
    const key = fn(x)
    if (!keys.has(key)) {
      keys.add(key)
      result.push(x)
    }
  })
  return result
}

const convert = pipe(
  sortBy(prop('id')),
  reverse,
  uniqBy(prop('contact_id'))
)

const arr = [{"contact_id": 2, "id": 1, "some_field": true}, {"contact_id": 3, "id": 2, "some_field": true}, {"contact_id": 4, "id": 3, "some_field": false}, {"contact_id": 3, "id": 4, "some_field": true}, {"contact_id": 4, "id": 5, "some_field": false}]


console.log(convert(arr))
```

Each of these except `uniqBy` is a nearly trivial implementation.  For the most part, these are **not** the implementations used in Ramda, which often has additional concerns.  But they should work mostly the same.

This is a great combination of reusable functions for which you could well find many other uses across your code-base.

---

Finally, while this does avoid having several reassignments, it does not remove the problem of having several iterations through the data.  In fact, because `sortBy` does not offer a `direction` parameter, we already have to add one more step: `sortBy`, *then* `reverse`. (It makes sense to do it like this because it's so easy to combine the `reverse` with `sortBy` that there is no reason for a function such as `reverseSortBy`.)  This is my preferred style of working.  I very rarely run into performance problems because of this, and I choose to deal with such issues only if the system is demonstrating measureable performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

Compare function passed to [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should return a number, not true or false.

You could map the array before sorting so you leave the original array as is. Then sort by contact_id first and id second. This allows you to remove duplicates in one go with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Sort again for the correct order:

```js
const org = [
  {
      id: 1,
      contact_id: 2,
      some_field: true
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      contact_id: 3,
      some_field: true
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      contact_id: 4,
      some_field: false
  },
  {
      id: 4,
      contact_id: 3,
      some_field: true
  },
  {
      id: 5,
      contact_id: 4,
      some_field: false
  }
];


console.log(
  org.map(x=>x)//sort mutates your array, this will prevent it from mutating
  .sort((a,b)=>a.contact_id-b.contact_id||b.id-a.id)//sort by contact_id first then by id
  .reduce(
    ([result,last],current)=>
      (last.contact_id===current.contact_id)
        ? [result,current]
        : [result.concat(current),current],
    [[],{}]//initial values for result and last
  )[0].sort((a,b)=>b.id-a.id)//sort by id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` to create an object with distinct `contact_id` and highest `id` for each `contact_id`. Then using `Object.values()`, get all the values from this object and sort it.

```js
const arr = [ { id: 1, contact_id: 2, some_field: true }, { id: 2, contact_id: 3, some_field: true }, { id: 3, contact_id: 4, some_field: false }, { id: 4, contact_id: 3, some_field: true }, { id: 5, contact_id: 4, some_field: false } ],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.contact_id] = r[o.contact_id] ? (r[o.contact_id].id < o.id ? {...o} : r[o.contact_id]) : {...o}
      return r;
    },{})).sort((a,b) => b.id - a.id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to keep track of unique contact_ids, you can do something like below.

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    contact_id: 2,
    some_field: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    contact_id: 3,
    some_field: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    contact_id: 4,
    some_field: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    contact_id: 3,
    some_field: true
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    contact_id: 4,
    some_field: false
  }
];

const contactIds = {};
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.id == b.id ? 0 : a.id > b.id ? -1 : 1;
}).map((obj) => {
  if (!contactIds[obj.contact_id]) {
    contactIds[obj.contact_id] = true;
    return obj;
  }
}).filter((item) => item !== undefined));
```

Comment: No need for the map though, you can just do: `.filter(obj => 
  (!contactIds[obj.contact_id]) && (contactIds[obj.contact_id]=true)
)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    function uniq_all_props (__arr1, __arr2, __by_prop) {
      let arr = __arr1.concat(__arr2)
      let set = []
      let result = []
      arr.forEach(function (__obj) {
        /** Set each obj to a string. */
        if (__by_prop) {
          let string = JSON.stringify(__obj[__by_prop])
          set.push(string)
        } else {
          let string = JSON.stringify(__obj)
          set.push(string)
        }
      })
      set.filter(function (elem, index, self) {
        /** Use filter as a loop to push onto results array.
         * This is done to preserve prop types from original arrays */
        if (index === self.indexOf(elem)) {
          result.push(arr[index])
        }
      })
      return result
    }

    let arr_1 = [{"id":1,"contact_id":2,"some_field":true},{"id":2,"contact_id":3,"some_field":true},{"id":3,"contact_id":4,"some_field":false},{"id":4,"contact_id":3,"some_field":true},{"id":5,"contact_id":4,"some_field":false}]

    let sorted_1 = arr_1.sort(function(a, b) { return b.id - a.id}) //Sort by 'id'
    let res_1 = uniq_all_props(sorted_1, [], 'contact_id') // Use prop 'contact_id' to determine unique objects

    console.log(res_1)

    /** result
     *
       [
         { id: 5, contact_id: 4, some_field: false },
         { id: 4, contact_id: 3, some_field: true },
         { id: 1, contact_id: 2, some_field: true }
       ]
     *
     * */
```